# Lift Web Framework query string generator

Tags: http, query-string, lift

How do you create a link with query string parameters:

```
/path/to/view?param=358&name=Something+with+spaces
```

in Lift? I know you can simply write it, I am looking for a wise approach, which encode spaces and other special characters. For example:

```
Link("path/to/view").param("param", 358).param("name", "Something with spaces")
```

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `appendParams` method in `net.liftweb.util.HttpHelpers` trait:

```
import net.liftweb._
import util.Helpers._

val url = appendParams("/path/to/view",
                      ("param" -> "358") ::
                      ("name" -> "Something with spaces") :: Nil)
```

Reply from Scala REPL:

```
url: String = /path/to/view?param=358&name=Something+with+spaces
```

As you can see, it gets URL as a String, `Seq` of param tuples and finally returns String.